# no puedo importar un modulo en Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, modulos, componentes

Tengo un modulo llamado home que contiene los componetes navbar y adentro un html con el navbar pero al momento de importarlo a otro modulo tengo el siguiente error:

> ```
>  src/app/acceso/login/login.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'app-navbar' is not a known element:
> 1. If 'app-navbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'app-navbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
>
> 1 <app-navbar></app-navbar>
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   src/app/acceso/login/login.component.ts:5:16
>     5   templateUrl: './login.component.html',
>                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     Error occurs in the template of component LoginComponent.
> ```

### ya importe el modulo home y el export del componete navbar

modulo Home

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NavbarComponent,
  ],
  exports:[
    NavbarComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

---

Modulo al que deseo importar el componte del home

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeModule } from '../home/home.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HomeModule
  ],
})
export class AccesoModule { }
```

Comment: El mensaje de error te dice que el componente LoginComponent tiene algún error en su plantilla, en el fichero `login.component.html` Revisa la sintaxis de ese fichero

Answer (score 0):

Si el caso es que necesitas 'llamar' al componente NavbarComponent en el componente LoginComponent, pienso que deberías importar el módulo Home en el módulo donde tengas declarado el componente Login. En el módulo AccesoModule del que muestras el código no aparecen componentes declarados. Si puedes ofrecer más información te lo agradezco.